# Validating Text input with val()

Tags: jquery, xss, validating-event

I try to validate the Input in my website because of Cross-Site-Scripting-Attacks!

```
<form name="SearchInput" class="form-inline filterForm" method="post" action="/annoncen/" onsubmit="validateMyForm();">
          <input type="text" name="searchWord" class="form-control form-search left" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Text" onkeyup="inputKeyUp(event)"/>
          <input type="text" name="searchLoc"  class="form-control form-search right" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Place" onkeyup="inputKeyUp(event)"/>
          <button type="submit">search</button>
 </form>
```

I use the validate() plugin to prevent the user put a script in the input field

```
function validateMyForm(){
       var text_value = $('#formGroupExampleInput').val();
       if(text_value!=='/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/') {
            alert("Enter Some Text In Input Field");
            event.preventDefault();
       }}
```

but every time I get `text_value =""` !!! What am I doing wrong

Comment: One thing, you cannot have same `id` attribute for more than one html element. In your case `id="formGroupExampleInput"` is repeated for both input text element

Answer (score 1):

Note that anything in Javascript (validation, encoding or whatever else) won't protect against reflected or stored XSS. You need to encode your output where it's written back to the page (presumably on the server side), but that part is not shown in the question. XSS by default is an output encoding problem, and it is less about input valudation, though if strict enough and under the right circumstances, server-side input validation might also prevent it.

If however this is a DOM XSS you are trying to prevent, it would still be better to implement proper output handling in Javascript (like for example using `.text()` of jQuery instead of `.html()` and so on) rather than trying to control input on the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Your value is always empty because there is two input with same ID.
here is an example with two different ID that works(formGroupExampleInput and formGroupExampleInput1)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function (e){     
      var text_value = $('#formGroupExampleInput').val();
      console.log('your value ' + text_value);
       if(text_value==="") {
            alert("Enter Some Text In Input Field");
            e.preventDefault();
       }
      console.log('form is submited');
       //todo remove this e.preventDefault(); to make your form submit
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="SearchInput" class="form-inline filterForm" >
          <input type="text" name="searchWord" class="form-control form-search left" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Text" />
          <input type="text" name="searchLoc"  class="form-control form-search right" id="formGroupExampleInput1" placeholder="Place" />
          <button type="submit">search</button>
 </form>
```

Concerning using regExp, you maybe should use `new RegExp()` and `test()` or `exec()`

[More info on regExp](https://www.toutjavascript.com/reference/ref-regexp.php)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var reg=new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}[/]{1}[0-9]{2}[/]{1}[0-9]{4}$","g");
var chaine1="15/12/2017";
var chaine2="1a/bb/2017";
document.write(chaine1+" ");
if (reg.test(chaine1)) {document.write("est bien au format date<BR>")}
else {document.write("n'est pas au format date<BR>")}
document.write(chaine2+" ");
if (reg.test(chaine2)) {document.write("est bien au format date")}
else {document.write("n'est pas au format date")}
</script>
```

Comment: How can I compair the text_value with a regex pattern ??

Comment: info concerning regExp use in answer... +1 'll appreciate.

Comment: Note that while all of this is of course correct, this will *not* solve XSS in your application, and the question started with trying to solve XSS.

Comment: @GaborLengyel you're absolutely rigth dude ! Validating a form will not protect against XSS... 
Your explanation above was complete... So i tried just to answer his code problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my Problem (in DOM ) with replace()

```
function validateMyForm(){
regex = /[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/g;
$('#formGroupExampleInput1').val($('#formGroupExampleInput1').val().replace(regex,' '));
$('#formGroupExampleInput2').val($('#formGroupExampleInput2').val().replace(regex,' '));}
```

I replace all the not allowed characters with plain text and prevent in his way the injecting of scripts !!

Comment: So again, this does not prevent injecting scripts. An attacker can send whatever request he wants, Javascript is not relevant in security-related input validation. So in other words, if your page was vulnerable to XSS before this change, it still is. The solution to XSS is output encoding anyway, and not primarily input validation.